# How to extract list of values from 2d list

Tags: python, list, arguments

How to extract list of values that meet some condition from 2d list ?

How to rid of empty lists and redundant brackets?

```
my_list = [[(i,j) for i in list_ if i == 1] for j,list_ in enumerate(grid)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
grid = [[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,1,12]]
results = [(i, b) for b in range(len(grid)) for i, a in enumerate(grid[b]) if a == 1]
```

Output:

```
[(2, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Where did you get `grid` values from?